# Python Could not import class

Tags: python-2.7, plone, zope

After transfer zope2 app from ubuntu12 to centos7, i get some errors that indicate that the classes are not loaded.
How to check if all required libs of python are imported?
How to fix these errors:

```
 WARNING OFS.Uninstalled Could not import class 'Photos' from module 'Products.Ezonus.projektai2.ezonus2.control.system.Photos'
------
 WARNING OFS.Uninstalled Could not import class 'FailuArchyvas' from module 'Products.Ezonus.projektai2.ezonus2.control.system.FailuArchyvas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting some kind of exception when these Python modules are being imported. To debug, you can find `ClassFactory.py` which is part of Zope2 and modify it directly to display the exact error message:

```
##############################################################################
#
# Copyright (c) 2002 Zope Foundation and Contributors.
# 
# This software is subject to the provisions of the Zope Public License,
# Version 2.1 (ZPL).  A copy of the ZPL should accompany this distribution.
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND ANY AND ALL EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES ARE DISCLAIMED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF TITLE, MERCHANTABILITY, AGAINST INFRINGEMENT, AND FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
# 
##############################################################################
"""Zope Framework Class Finder
"""
import OFS.Uninstalled

def ClassFactory(jar, module, name,
                  _silly=('__doc__',), _globals={},
                  ):

    # Add the following code:
    if module in [
        'Products.Ezonus.projektai2.ezonus2.control.system.Photos',
        'Products.Ezonus.projektai2.ezonus2.control.system.FailuArchyvas'
    ]:
        m=__import__(module, _globals, _globals, _silly)
    # ^^^

    try:
        m=__import__(module, _globals, _globals, _silly)
        return getattr(m, name)
    except:
        return OFS.Uninstalled.Broken(jar, None, (module, name))
```

Where, for me, the exact file path was `eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/ClassFactory.py`.

Most likely, you are missing some Ubuntu packages which need to be installed.